# Make GHCi load a source file in any state, and just throw errors at runtime

Tags: haskell

When I am modifying an Haskell file, I find myself many times wanting to test a function that I finished, while others are yet to be completed or broken.

However, when I try to load in GHCi, it forces me to fix the other functions too, and this is too much annoying.

How can I tell GHCi to load any file, and just throw errors at runtime?

What I would like is a way to ajdust the "rigidity" of error checking.

This would be very useful for interative development.

Comment: Any problem with `myOtherFunction = undefined` or just commenting it out?

Comment: If you are in the middle of a big modification and have too many functions with already much code, that is unworkable

Comment: Is [this](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/defer-type-errors.html) useful?

Comment: @lortabac Yep, that is very useful! Is there any way to configure GHCi to launch with the flag `-fdefer-type-errors` turned on by default?

Comment: @mljrg You can add a line containing `:set -fdefer-type-errors` to `~/.ghci` (or to a project-specific `.ghci` if that's preferred).